# How to incorporate an attribute that only exists in some observations?

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-engineering, missing-data

In a binary classification problem, some of my observations have an event that occurs. I can, obviously, add a 1/0 flag if the event occurs ("event_occurred" in the data below). However, my intuition is that the class is related to the number of days since that event occurred. I'd like to somehow include the number of days since the event occurred in my model ("days_since_event").

Example python data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'event_date': 
                   pd.Series(['2019-02-25','','2019-01-31','','2019-03-03']),
                   'event_occurred': pd.Series([1,0,1,0,1]),
                   'days_since_event': pd.Series([42, '', 67, '', 36]),
                   'class': pd.Series([1,2,2,1,1])})

    event_date  event_occurred  days_since_event  class
0   2019-02-25               1                42      1
1                            0                        2
2   2019-01-31               1                67      2
3                            0                        1
4   2019-03-03               1                36      1
```

Is this a standard missing data problem or is there a way to better represent this data in a model-friendly format? Is this a situation where I can fill the missing observations with a global value and trust that the model will learn to ignore that value if "event_occurred" is 0?

Comment: Do you have any particular model in mind? That might help answer your question. Most tree based models, for example, would be able to handle this kind of situation without having to replace the missing values.

Comment: I've been using logistic regression but I wanted to try gradient-boosted decision trees via LightGBM too. It looks like LightGBM can [handle missing values](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Advanced-Topics.rst) out of the box like you suggested. I'll give that a try, thanks!